# split window and rearange parts on screen

Tags: linux, xorg, split-window

I have third party application with the native resolution of 1600x600. What I need is to display first 800x600 half of the window below the second 800x600 part of the window.

This wasn't problem as long as I had two separate monitors for this task (used xrandr and physically moved monitors around as needed).

But now I have one 32" widescreen monitor with portrait orientation. I used virtual box with two virtual monitors and the Tiling Window Manager to simulate two real monitor scenario for this, but it seems to me bit tricky.

Is there some simpler solution available?